# ember-cli-facebook-js-sdk error TypeError: _npmEmberCliFacebookJsSdk.default.init is not a function

Tags: ember.js, facebook-share

When I run the server, I get following error in browser console

```
TypeError: _npmEmberCliFacebookJsSdk.default.init is not a function
```

Following is the code:

```
import FB from 'npm:ember-cli-facebook-js-sdk';

export default {
  name: 'fb',
  initialize: function() {
    return FB.init({
      appId: 'My-App-ID',
      version: 'v2.8',
      xfbml: true
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: A cursory reading of the docs for ember-cli-facebook-js-sdk show you are not using it according to the guide.  The initialization method is called `FBInit`, not `FB.init`.

Answer (score 1):

You should generate a instance-initializer with this command

ember g instance-initializer fb

And insert this code in this file

```
export function initialize(appInstance) {
  // appInstance.inject('route', 'foo', 'service:foo');
  appInstance.inject('controller', 'fb', 'service:fb');
  appInstance.inject('route', 'fb', 'service:fb');
}

export default {
  name: 'fb',
  initialize
};
```

UPDATE:
So if you are searching how login ember app with facebook using facebook sdk see my repo in github.

https://github.com/halleyrv/ember-facebook-sdk-login

Regards

Comment: So if you are searching how login ember app with facebook using facebook sdk see my repo in github.

https://github.com/halleyrv/ember-facebook-sdk-login

Regards